# Excel API - table.columns.load() fails if table is filtered on "blanks" or "null"

Tags: excel, office-js

When loading the filters for a table (`table.columns.load("filter")`), if the filter is applied to either `null` or `(blanks)` it returns the following error:

```json
{
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "message": "There was an internal error while processing the request.",
    "errorLocation": "Filter.criteria"
}
```

This can be replicated in ScriptLab using this snippet: https://gist.github.com/jimbarrett33/59926acf035a0739447890664d798cab.

Using the ScriptLab snippet, you can reproduce this error using the following steps:

1. Select `Create Table` from the add-in
2. Open the filter for the `Category` column
3. Deselect either `null` or `(blanks)` (one or the other, not both but more on that later)
4. Select `Get Table Columns` from the add-in

Regarding #3, if you select *both* `null` and `(blanks)` (or in combination with some other value) it succeeds. This issue only occurs when *only* `null` or *only* `(blanks)` is filtered out.

Note that in Excel Online running in Chrome, `(blanks)` works correctly but `null` continues to fail.